# Declaring constants instead of literals in vertex shader. Standard practice, or needless rigor?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es-2.0

In a **vertex shader**, there is of course a limited amount of **uniform storage** allowed, and it is my understanding that different systems may implement GLSL in slightly different ways in terms of compiling code. I've heard the recommendation to use constants instead of writing out literals in the vertex shader code.

For instance, the following code could *supposedly* result in a reduction in available uniform storage. (I don't quite understand how.)

*Example 1: With literals*

```
vec4 myVector = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

To my understanding, there is the possibility that each use of `1.0`or `0.0` takes up some amount of the uniform storage space. The recommendation is therefore to turn that previous code into something like the following:

*Example 2: With constants instead of literals*

```
const float zero = 0.0;
const float one = 1.0;

vec4 myVector = vec4(one, zero, zero, one);
```

Does anyone understand the argument behind what's going on? I'm not having any problems with code, I'm just trying to understand the stuff properly so that I don't have problems in the future.

**My formal question is the following:** specifically for the **iOS** platform using **OpenGL ES 2.0**, is the best practice to write out the thing with the literals (example 1), or with constants (example 2). Should I spend my time writing things out with constants each and every time, or should I write out literals and only use constants if the vertex shader fails to compile properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you look at the binary and see if there's any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Kimi's mention about not finding anything in the spec, Appendix A-7 of [The OpenGL®
 ES Shading Language](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) spec does include the following:

> When calculating the number of uniform variables used, any literal
>   constants present in the shader source  after preprocessing are
>   included when calculating the storage requirements. Multiple instances
>   of  identical constants should count multiple times.

This is probably the source of the recommendation in [OpenGL® ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://opengles-book.com/) that Kimi quotes.

However, the spec does not mandate this restriction, and presumably any implementation is free to improve on it, but I cannot find anything either way regarding the iOS GL drivers.

I'm curious, did anyone actually follow up on the ideas of overloading a sample shader with literals, in an attempt to reach any potential maximum uniform limit?

*(Sorry...I had intended to post this answer as a comment to Kimi's answer, but don't have the required 50 Rep points yet).*

Answer (score 1):

From the [OpenGL® ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://opengles-book.com)

> As far as literal values are concerned, the OpenGL ES 2.0 shading
>   language spec states that no constant propagation is assumed. This
>   means that multiple instances of the same literal value(s) will be
>   counted multiple times. Instead of using literal values, appropriate
>   const variables should be declared. This avoids having the same
>   literal value count multiple times, which might cause the vertex
>   shader to fail to compile if vertex uniform storage requirements
>   exceed what the implementation supports.

I could not find anything related to this in the actual spec. Also there is no information specific to the iOS.

Also you can check a [GLSL Optimizer](https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer) tool written to tackle this issue (and lots of others).

Comment: Thanks Kimi, that's what I was reading when I came up with the question. What I might do is just type in a bunch of literals and see if it fails to compile at some point, and then just swap them with constants and see if it changes. My thought in reading the Programming Guide was that the author could potentially be trying to make suggestions that would work across all platforms, and I so I was essentially wondering whether the iOS implementation of the vertex shader compiler concerned itself with this issue or not. It's not a super-urgent question, but if I find an answer, I'll post it.