# Open GL ES 2.0 program working on Android 3.1 but failed to run on Android 4.0+

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I wrote a 3D rendering program using Android Open GL ES2.0 Java API. It works well on my Xoom which runs Android 3.1.

I am trying to run it on HTC Evo 3D and Samsung Galaxy S4 whose Android Versions are 4.0.3 and 4.2 respectively. No rendering is shown. A black window on GLSurface View. Logcat shows error message "Could not compile shader 35633(35632):" and "E/Adreno200-ES20(15586): <__load_uniform_int:258>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION"

What changed from 3.1 to 4.0 that makes the shaders fail to compile?

The program shows the moon orbiting the earth. It implements dynamic shadow caused by a light resembling sun. It also implements specular light caused by that light on earth's ocean surface.

Earth vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 aPosition;   
attribute vec3 aNormal;   
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;   

varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord;   
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying1;
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying2;
varying vec4 vPosition;    
varying vec3 nPos;
varying vec3 vNormal;

uniform vec3 uLight1Position;   
uniform vec4 uLight1Color;
uniform vec3 uLight2Position;   
uniform vec4 uLight2Color;
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform vec4 uAmbientLight;

void main() {   
  vTextureCoord.x = aTextureCoord.x;   
  vTextureCoord.y = aTextureCoord.y;   
  vNormal = normalize(aNormal);  

  vPosition = aPosition;
  nPos = aPosition.xyz / aPosition.w;
  float nDotVP1 = max(0.0, dot(vNormal, normalize(uLight1Position - nPos)));  
  float nDotVP2 = max(0.0, dot(vNormal, normalize(uLight2Position - nPos)));  

  vec4 diffuse1 = uLight1Color * nDotVP1;
  colorVarying1 = diffuse1;
  colorVarying2 = uLight2Color * nDotVP2;
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;

};
```

The following is earth fragment shader.

```
precision highp float;

const vec4 bitShifts = vec4(1.0 / (256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0),
                1.0 / (256.0 * 256.0),
                1.0 / 256.0,
                1.0);

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying1; 
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying2; 
varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord; 
varying vec4 vPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 nPos;

uniform sampler2D sTexture;  
uniform sampler2D sCloudTexture;  
uniform sampler2D sDepthMapLight1;  
uniform sampler2D sDepthMapLight2;  

uniform float uHeightOfLight1Frustum;
uniform float uHeightOfLight2Frustum;
uniform vec3 uLight1Position;   
uniform vec4 uLight1Color;
uniform vec3 uLight2Position;   
uniform vec4 uLight2Color;
uniform mat4 uLight1MVPMatrix;   
uniform mat4 uLight2MVPMatrix;   
uniform vec4 uAmbientLight;
uniform vec3 uEyePosition;
uniform vec4 uCenterOfSphere;


float unpack(vec4 rgba){
  return dot(rgba, bitShifts);
};

void main() { 
  vec4 surfaceColor;
  vec4 cloudColor; 
  vec3 incoming1 = nPos - uLight1Position;
  vec3 reflected1 = normalize(reflect(incoming1, vNormal));
  vec3 incoming2 = nPos - uLight2Position;
  vec3 reflected2 = normalize(reflect(incoming2, vNormal));
  vec3 posToEye = normalize(uEyePosition - nPos);

  float shininess = 60.0;
  vec4 specular1 = uLight1Color * 5.0 * pow(max(0.0, dot(reflected1,posToEye)), shininess);
  vec4 specular2 = uLight2Color * 5.0 * pow(max(0.0, dot(reflected2,posToEye)), shininess);
  surfaceColor=texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
  if(surfaceColor.x > surfaceColor.z || surfaceColor.y > surfaceColor.z)
    specular1 = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

  cloudColor=texture2D(sCloudTexture, vTextureCoord);
  vec4 depth1Un = uLight1MVPMatrix * vPosition;
  vec3 depth1 = depth1Un.xyz / depth1Un.w;
  vec4 depth2Un = uLight2MVPMatrix * vPosition;
  vec3 depth2 = depth2Un.xyz / depth2Un.w;

  depth1.z = length(vPosition.xyz - uLight1Position) / uHeightOfLight1Frustum;
  depth2.z = length(vPosition.xyz - uLight2Position) / uHeightOfLight2Frustum;
  vec2 coord1 = vec2((depth1.x+1.0)/2.0, (depth1.y+1.0)/2.0);
  vec2 coord2 = vec2((depth2.x+1.0)/2.0, (depth2.y+1.0)/2.0);

  vec4 moveToCenter = uCenterOfSphere * 0.01 + vPosition * 0.99;
  vec4 depthShifted1Un = uLight1MVPMatrix * moveToCenter;
  vec3 depthShifted1 = depthShifted1Un.xyz / depthShifted1Un.w;
  vec4 depthShifted2Un = uLight2MVPMatrix * moveToCenter;
  vec3 depthShifted2 = depthShifted2Un.xyz / depthShifted2Un.w;

  vec2 coordShifted1 = vec2((depthShifted1.x+1.0)/2.0, (depthShifted1.y+1.0)/2.0);
  vec2 coordShifted2 = vec2((depthShifted2.x+1.0)/2.0, (depthShifted2.y+1.0)/2.0);

  float shadow1 = 1.0;
  float shadowDepth1 = unpack(texture2D(sDepthMapLight1, coord1));
  float shadowDepthShifted1 = unpack(texture2D(sDepthMapLight1, coordShifted1));
  if ( depth1.z >= shadowDepthShifted1 * 1.02 ){
       shadow1 = 0.0;
  }

  float shadow2 = 1.0;    
  float shadowDepth2 = unpack(texture2D(sDepthMapLight2, coord2));
  float shadowDepthShifted2 = unpack(texture2D(sDepthMapLight2, coordShifted2));
  if ( depth2.z >= shadowDepthShifted2 * 1.02 ){
       shadow2 = 0.0;
  }

  vec4 totalLight4 = (colorVarying1 + specular1) * shadow1 + uAmbientLight;

  if(cloudColor[0]>0.3) {
    cloudColor[3]=0.5;  
    gl_FragColor=(cloudColor*1.3 + surfaceColor*.4) * totalLight4; 
  } else {
  gl_FragColor = surfaceColor * totalLight4;
  }
};
```

Comment: Please provide full code of shader - vertex and fragment. And my guess is that this is related to different GPUs of devices, not Android version.

Comment: What is full shader compilation error? Could you please add full logcat errors? Because you don't know exact problematic line of code I'd suggest you to comment out shader code part by part to narrow down line causing compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Because your shader uses quite a lot of uniforms you might run out of available uniform vectors for certain GPUs. You should check values of `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` and `GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS` on these devices.

Also, please note that literals are actually taking uniform vectors, even 2 literals w/ the same values actually use 2 uniforms. So your shader uses quite a lot of implicit uniforms.

You can find more detailed information in this question: [Declaring constants instead of literals in vertex shader. Standard practice, or needless rigor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963765/declaring-constants-instead-of-literals-in-vertex-shader-standard-practice-or)