# Why doesn't my simple fragment shader work on iOS but not Android under Cocos2d-x 3.2?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x, shader, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have modified a working grey_scale fragment shader to change all of the non-transparent pixels to purple. For some reason it works great on iOS but on Android the transparent parts of the image are visible (although mostly transparent). Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

The working grey_scale shader contains the lines that are commented out. I added the last line.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 c = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);

    //gl_FragColor.xyz = vec3(0.2126*c.r + 0.7152*c.g + 0.0722*c.b);
    //gl_FragColor.w = c.w;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.4, c.w);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I need to apply the alpha to all of the colors:

```
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5*c.w, 0.0*c.w, 0.4*c.w, c.w);
```

I am sure why the old method didn't work. The image uses premultiplied alpha, so I guess the cocos render assumes it (or was somehow told to use it by TexturePacker). So the shader needs to re-multiply the color values by the alpha in order to behave the same way?

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot will be worth a thousands of words.

Are you sure `GL_ES` is defined? If not, you will have unspecified precision for `float` (according to specs, it is unspecified for fragment shaders) which can lead even to compilation errors on certain OpenGL ES drivers. I'd play around with that float precision first and see the difference on Android.

I'm not sure about `vec3()` w/ single parameter. Does the following notation work:

```
float a = 0.2126*c.r + 0.7152*c.g + 0.0722*c.b;
gl_FragColor.xyz = vec3(a, a, a);
```

Or this, with a single assignment of gl_FragColor:

```
float a = 0.2126*c.r + 0.7152*c.g + 0.0722*c.b;
gl_FragColor.xyz = vec4(a, a, a, c.w);
```

On a side note, you may want to declare numeric literals as constants in order not to consume uniform space. More info: [Declaring constants instead of literals in vertex shader. Standard practice, or needless rigor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963765/declaring-constants-instead-of-literals-in-vertex-shader-standard-practice-or)

Like this:

```
const float COEFF_R = 0.2126;
const float COEFF_G = 0.7152;
const float COEFF_B = 0.0722;

float a = COEFF_R*c.r + COEFF_G*c.g + COEFF_B*c.b;
gl_FragColor.xyz = vec4(a, a, a, c.w);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's an unreleased game, so I couldn't post a screenshot. Cheers